# AttributeError: attribute 'FileStream' of 'namespace#' object is read-only

Tags: python, wpf

I am trying to make my first WPF in IronPython 2.7 in Dynamo.

To avoid bundling an image, I am trying to pull it from the web, then seemingly I need to convert it to a different type of bitmap, so i can then insert it to the WPF.

As noted above, I am getting this error "AttributeError: attribute 'FileStream' of 'namespace#' object is read-only".

This is the pertinent part of my code...

```
logo = PictureBox()
myImage = System.Windows.Controls.Image()
bitmapImage = BitmapImage()
bitmapImage.BeginInit()                
bitmapImage.UriSource =  Uri("https://www.dyna-sco.co.uk/uploads/1/2/7/0/127043387/" + "dyna-sco-logo1_orig.png")
bitmapImage.EndInit()   
myImage.Source = bitmapImage        
stream = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.FileStream(bitmapImage.UriSource, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
encoder = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BmpBitmapEncoder()
encoder.Frames.Add(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapImage))
encoder.Save(stream)
logo.Image = bitmapImage
```

All Comments and thoughts (relating to any part of the code) are greatly appreciated.  I am flailing around in the dark right now :)

I have read every post i can find, but none have helped.

Cheers,

Mark

Comment: What is `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.FileStream` supposed to be? It should certainly be `System.IO.FileStream`. You can also not pass an Uri as first constructor argument. It should be a file path string. Also, assigning `logo.Image = bitmapImage` will not work, because PictureBox is WinForms, while BitmapImage is WPF.

Comment: "*then seemingly I need to convert it to a different type of bitmap, so i can then insert it to the WPF*" - that is totally wrong. All code after `myImage.Source = bitmapImage` is useless. You should however add the Image element `myImage`to the visual tree of your application, i.e. put it into some parent container.

Comment: Note also that you don't strictly need to call BeginInit and EndInit. You could as well write `bitmapImage = BitmapImage(Uri("https://www.dyna-sco.co.uk/uploads/1/2/7/0/127043387/" + "dyna-sco-logo1_orig.png"))`.

Comment: Thanks :) </code>You can also not pass an Uri as first constructor argument. It should be a file path string</code> I would ideally like to pull an URL without saving, is there a (method for converting to a) stream which can do so? Cheers